# Map types nesting issue

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to create this sort of Map:

```
var map:Map = new Map<Dynamic, Array<ProductData>>();
```

But compiler throws an error `: Unexpected ;`
So it doesn't like the types declaration nesting. But I really do need that `Array<ProductData>` as a value of a map.

How can I overcome this mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting, since I get a different error with that code:

> Invalid number of type parameters for Map

That is fixed by removing the `:Map` though (just let type inference handle that).

After that, though, I get the following error:

> Abstract Map has no @:to function that accepts IMap>

...or in other words - you can't have a `Map` with `Dynamic` keys in Haxe. Why are you using `Dynamic` there in the first place? Could that maybe be statically typed?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same results. Are you using the Haxe 3.1.3?

Comment: Gama, I changed Dynamic to DisplayObject (which is ok for my app) and it's working fine. But I have here another similar Map with this structure var conditionFlagButtonsMap = new Map<ConditionFlag, Array<PushButton>>();  and when I try to write conditionFlagButtonsMap.set(  I get the  "Cannot create closure on abstract inline method" error! ConditionFlag i enum btw. I changed it to String and I still get this result. Don't you have any ideas?